# How to do a form submit in moodle from some other page?

Tags: forms, post, moodle

In moodle, when you go to Quiz Administration-> User overrides -> Add user override, you get a form (overrideedit.php) to add the details of the user override to be created.
You need to fill that form and submit it. After you submit, the form is processed (in overrideedit.php itself) and then you are redirected to overrides.php page.
Now, I want that form to take post data from my plugin and process it in overrideedit.php and do the redirect.
How do I send post data in this case from my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a different action for the form you're having in your plugin (this assumes you are using Moodle Form API for your custom form):

```
// Instantiate your form
// Data will be submitted to /mod/quiz/overrideedit.php
$mform = new custom_form_your_are_having(new moodle_url('/mod/quiz/overrideedit.php'));
```

Or simply change the action attribute of your custom for to point to `/mod/quiz/overrideedit.php`:

```
<form action="/mod/quiz/overrideedit.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Comment: The override_form is displayed in overrideedit.php itself. I need to fill that form data from my plugin and do the submit.